# Flashing is appearing on reloading the activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to reload my MainActivity from the adapter. Please find the code below:

```
 activity = (Activity) context;
            activity.finish();
            activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            Intent intent =((Activity) context).getIntent();
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

The issue is, even after adding this code block, the flashing animation is still appearing during the reloading of the activity.

Inside the adapter, I am showing one dialog. On pressing a button, the dialog results in reloading of the activity.

Inside onBindViewHolder():

```
   viewHolder.txtv_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int_timer = 0;
            tickValue = true;
            timerGroupChatHistory.start();
            getChatHistory(alst_Dealitem.get(i));

        }
    });
```

Inside Chat History, I am calling ShowChatDialog():

```
 public void show_chatDialog(final ArrayList<chatObject> alst_chatHistoryList, final String refNumber)
{
    final Dialog dlg_dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.Theme_Dialog);
    // dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dlg_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Window window = dlg_dialog.getWindow();
    if (window == null) return;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dlg_dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    dlg_dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    //dialog.setContentView(R.layout.new_field_quote_entry_dialog);
    dlg_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    dlg_dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    //dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    dlg_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.chat_history_dialog);

    final RecyclerView rvw_chatHistoryList = (RecyclerView)dlg_dialog.findViewById(R.id.chatHistoryList);
    final EditText etxt_chatText = (EditText)dlg_dialog.findViewById(R.id.chat_type);
    final LinearLayout lnrl_mainLayout = (LinearLayout)dlg_dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_main_layout);
    TextView txtv_send = (TextView) dlg_dialog.findViewById(R.id.chat_send);
    TextView txtv_title = (TextView)dlg_dialog.findViewById(R.id.chat_text) ;
    LinearLayout lnrl_back = (LinearLayout) dlg_dialog.findViewById(R.id.chat_backbutton) ;

    txtv_title.setText(refNumber);
    lnrl_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            activity.finish();
            activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            Intent intent =((Activity) context).getIntent();
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);




        }
    });
```

Is there anything I am missing? please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post more code.

Comment: @Anonymous: Please check the updated code.